# Convergence of $\frac1m(I+A+A^2+\cdots+A^{m-1})$

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix of nonnegative entries such that $A_{i1}+A_{i2}+\cdots+A_{in}=1$ for all $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. What does $A$ have to satisfy so that the sequence

$$M_m=\frac1m(I+A+A^2+\cdots+A^{m-1})$$

converge?

I believe this converges for almost all $A$. It should converge to a matrix $M$ such that $MA=M$ and $M_{i1}+M_{i2}+\cdots+M_{in}=1$ for all $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. I am pretty sure all of the rows of $M$ are equal most of the time, but I haven't found a rigorous proof. For what I need, I'm interested in something like $|M_m-M|<\epsilon\ll 1$ (for some norm $|\cdot|$, taxicab norm preferred). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are your entries non-negative or not?

Comment: Yes! Nonnegative. I edited that in the question. Thanks.

Comment: In probabilistic terms, this is the law of large numbers for a finite Markov chain.

Comment: @NateEldredge This also seems to be some type of Ergodic Theorem for Dynamical Systems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your matrix is stochastic, if it is also primitive then the largest eigenvalue is $1$, and all the other eigenvalues satisfy

$$ | \lambda | <1 \,.$$

What you need is $\#5$ from here:
[Properties of Perron-Frobenius Eigenvalue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem#Further_properties)

What is says is the following:

Let $A$ be any primitive matrix and $r$ be the Perron-Frobenius eigenvalue (in your case $r=1$).

Then

$$\frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=0}^m \frac{A^i}{r^i} \to vw^t$$

where $v,w$ are the left and right PF-eigenvectors normalized by $w^t v=1$.

There is a reference to this result....

**P.S.** In order to be Primitive, all entries need to be positive. If this doesn't happen, just check the section "Perron projection as a limit: $A^k/r^k$", it actually have the idea of the proof of this result under pretty general settings....

Comment: It is not *quite* true that the other eigenvalues $\lambda$ of any stochastic matrix satisfy $|\lambda|<1$. The convergence, however, is true for **any** stochastic matrix.

Comment: edited, that's why I added the part about primitivity at the end, but forgot to change in the beginning...